# почему компилятор Open Watcom(wcc386) неккоректно компилирует код

Tags: c, компиляция, компилятор, стандарт

я установил себе на компьютер **Open Watcom** и что бы протестировать компилятор я взял код из Интернета на Си и решил скомпилировать, но получил вот такое от компилятора:

```
f.c(11): Error! E1077: Missing '}'
f.c(11): Warning! W107: Missing return value for function 'main'
f.c(11): Error! E1061: Expecting data or function declaration, but found '{'
f.c(12): Error! E1026: Invalid declarator
f.c(12): Error! E1009: Expecting ';' but found 'char'
f.c(13): Warning! W132: No storage class or type specified
f.c(13): Error! E1129: Type does not agree with previous definition of 'n'
f.c(13): Note! I2002: 'n' defined in: f.c(11)
f.c(13): Error! E1011: Symbol 'argv' has not been declared
f.c(13): Error! E1045: Subscript on non-array
f.c(13): Warning! W100: Parameter 2 contains inconsistent levels of indirection
f.c(13): Note! I2003: source conversion type is 'char **'
f.c(13): Note! I2004: target conversion type is 'char const *'
f.c(13): Error! E1151: Parameter count does not agree with previous definition
f.c(13): Note! I2002: 'strtol' defined in: D:\Programms\Watcom\H\stdlib.h(221)
f.c(13): Error! E1054: Expression must be constant
f.c(14): Error! E1009: Expecting ')' but found '>'
f.c(14): Error! E1009: Expecting ')' but found 'argv'
f.c(14): Warning! W132: No storage class or type specified
f.c(14): Error! E1129: Type does not agree with previous definition of 'tail'
f.c(14): Note! I2002: 'tail' defined in: f.c(12)
f.c(14): Error! E1009: Expecting ';' but found ')'
f.c(14): Error! E1061: Expecting data or function declaration, but found ')'
f.c(14): Error! E1026: Invalid declarator
f.c(14): Error! E1009: Expecting ';' but found '?'
f.c(14): Error! E1061: Expecting data or function declaration, but found '?'
f.c(14): Error! E1009: Expecting ')' but found 'void'
f.c(14): Error! E1026: Invalid declarator
f.c(14): Error! E1009: Expecting ';' but found ')'
f.c(14): Error! E1147: Too many errors: compilation aborted
```

Вот почему он некорректно компилирует?

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  assert (argc - 1 == 1);
  long n;
  {
    char *tail;
    n = strtol (argv[1], &tail, 0);
    assert (tail > argv[1]);
    assert (*tail == '\0');
  }

  assert (n >= 1);
  assert (n <= sqrt (LONG_MAX));
  const int width = (int)ceil (2 * log (1 + n) / log (10));

  long i;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    long j;
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
      printf (" %*ld", width, i * j);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какие параметры компилятору вы передавали?

Comment: я передавал параметр -bt=nt f.c , где f.c файл с кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что OW - достаточно старый компилятор, и новомодные :) веяния в C он не поддерживает. Ваш код вполне компилируем в режиме C++, но в режиме C ему хочется - по старой классике - собрать все объявления переменных в начале функции:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long n, i;
    char *tail;
    int width;
    assert(argc - 1 == 1);
    n = strtol (argv[1], &tail, 0);
    assert (tail > argv[1]);
    assert (*tail == '\0');
    assert (n >= 1);
    assert (n <= sqrt (LONG_MAX));
    width = ceil(2*log(1+n)/log(10));
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        long j;
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            printf (" %*ld", width, i * j);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вот так все заработает...

Кстати, а какая нынче версия OW? Что-то новее 1.9 появилось?
А когда-то был очень крутой компилятор для своего времени...

Comment: спасибо, ничего новее 1.90 не появилось